# Why are there so many depictions of pre-Christian gods built in Medieval and Renaissance Rome?

Tags: middle-ages, art

I wonder why Church officials not only allowed but also endorsed and paid for depictions of pre-Christian gods.

Examples include Pietro Bracci's Oceanus, which was funded by the Pope,

[image]

and multiple others like this depiction of Venus and Mars.
[image]

These works were created even at those times when for worshiping Jesus Christ somewhat different way you could be easily burned alive.

Comment: "These works were created even at those times when for worshipping Jesus Christ somewhat different way you could be easily burned alive." Citation needed. Furthermore you got your timelines mixed up, Pietro Bracci was born two centuries _after_ the middle ages, and technically also after the Renaissance. There's a good question in there, but you really need to research the subject a bit on your own, at least until you get some of the basic facts straight.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos this depends on the definition of middle ages. Here it is traditionally defined as a time period up to French revolution (i.e., the Modern)

Comment: Hm? Where's that definition coming from?

Comment: @Yannis Rizos it is typical for Soviet and post-Soviet school. They usually assume Middle Ages to cover the time span of Feudalism and to end with the rise of Capitalism which is symbolized by the French revolution.

Comment: If that's true, it's quite misguiding and unfortunate. How about you revise your question to follow the commonly accepted definition of middle ages, since this isn't really a Soviet or a post Soviet school.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos the question asks about middle ages and renaissance, so what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that Middle Ages typically refers to the period between the 5th and 15th century, and Renaissance to the period between the 15th and 17th century. Your question is already _extremely_ broad, even if we don't take your definition of Middle Ages into account.

Comment: Timeframe specifics shouldn't impact the ability to provide some answer. I'm thinking this should be reopened. Afterall, we answer questions like *"Where did ancient Romans buy slaves from?"* even though the timeframe of ancient Rome is also disputed.

Comment: This question is nominated for re-opening; I don't see any edits to address the issues raised. Is the core question "Why do Christian artists depict pre-Christian mythology?".

Comment: The term "Middle age" is somewhat ambiguous. Of the images you give, the second is of 16th century, and this is Renaissance. "Renaissance" by definition is the renaissance of antiquity. The interest to antiquity was very great and it inspired artists. And the first image is of even later epoch, 18th century, the age of Enlightenment and  widespread atheism.